# Multi table inheritance in django

Tags: python, django

I'm using multi table inheritance in django. Model Ninja inherits from Person. In my tests, I'm creating two Ninja instances and one Person instance. I'm doing:

```
self.assertEquals(Person.objects.count(), 3)
```

But count is 1. Why isn't it 3? I was under the impression that a Person table is created for every Ninja.

Comment: You're correct- if you have 2 `Ninja` instances and 1 `Person` instance `Person.objects.count()` will be 3. There must be something else happening. Perhaps you should show the creation code. Are you saving the instances?

Comment: I should note that counting ninjas returns 2.

Comment: I'm creating the database with json fixtures. Another strange behavior : Ninja.objects.all() returns an empty list, but Person.objects.all() return the one non-ninja instance.

Comment: Is there a way to just inspect the database and see what's going on?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is with the fixtures. If you created the three instances, then used dumpdata to create fixtures, you would see three `Person` instances in the fixtures.

Comment: You can always inspect the database using 'manage.py dbshell', if you know your way around with SQL.
But, as other people have mentioned, without your (model) code and fixtures, it is hard to come up with what's going on.

Comment: Could you post your code, Otherwise we are at risk of discussing for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your description, a Ninja is a Person. Therefore, you have three Persons: 1 regular, 2 Ninja.

This is intended behavior. If you want to know the Persons who are not anything else (not Ninja, in your case), you have to explicitly ask the ORM for it. For example:

```
Person.objects.
  exclude(id__in=Ninja.objects.values('id')).
  exclude(id__in=SomeOtherPersonSubclass.objects.values('id'))
```

I'm not sure the code is correct/working, but I think it conveys the idea.

The fact that your database isn't behaving as expected (as you talked about in the comments) is because, in order to have a Ninja instance, it needs it Person "part", so to speak. You'd have to have something like:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Hattori",
      "last_name": "Hanzo"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.ninja",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "super_power": "fearless tactics"
    }
  }
]
```